# If $(m,n)=1$ and $mn=r^2$ for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, prove that $m$ and $n$ are squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Honestly unsure how to proceed with this; I have some thoughts but don't know where to go with them.

$(m,n)=1\Longrightarrow m\nmid n$ and $n\nmid m$. But $mn=r^2$, so $\frac{r^2}{mn}=1$, and $mn\mid r^2$, and certainly $r^2\mid mn$ and by extention, $r\mid mn$.

Comment: Factor rsquared. Each prime factor must occur an even number of times. Primes must be assigned to m and n with no overlap, so both m and n will be perfect squares. You need to understand this. It is used in the elementary derivation of Pythagorean triples.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In the prime decomposition of $r^2$, each prime occurs twice. Let $p$ be one of the primes in the decomposition. What can you deduce from knowing $p \mid mn$?

Comment: $p\mid mn\Longrightarrow p\mid m$ or $p\mid n$...

Comment: Correct. Now as $r^2$ is a perfect square, we know that $p^{2k} \mid r^2$ for some $k$, so $p^{2k} \mid mn$. What can we deduce from this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by $p^{2k}$.. do you mean some prime squared?

Comment: Not necessarily squared, I just mean the the heighest power of $p$ which divides $r^2$; $p^k$ divides $r$ for some $k$, so $p^{2k}$ divides $r^2$. Consider $r = 12$. We have $r^2 = 144$, and the prime $2$ is a factor of $144$, in fact $2^4 \mid 144$.

Comment: Well, I'm tempted to try and use Euclid's Divsibility Theorem again, but $p^{2k}$ is not prime, so we can't say $p^{2k}\mid m$ or $p^{2k}\mid n$.

Comment: Suppose $p^{2k}$ is not a factor of $m$ or $n$. Then $p^a \mid m$ and $p^b \mid n$ for some $a, b$ such that $a + b = 2k$. Is that possible?

Comment: I suppose that's true only if $a=b$...

Comment: What is $(m, n)$ in that case?

Comment: Certainly greater than 1... I'm a bit tired so I want to guess $2$ but I don't think that's right.

Comment: It is greater than $1$, that's all that matters. We are told that $(m, n) = 1$ so it can't possibly be the case.

Comment: Well, thanks for the tips. I'm gonna sleep on it and hopefully it'll make sense in the morning. I'm a bit too tired to process much of anything sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Note the following statemtent holds:

```
'If an integer is an square it's a product of finite number of squares of prime numbers'
```

Also it holds other way around:

```
'If in a product the factors are squares of prime numbers, then also the product is an square.'
```

Note that this doesn't just hold for prime numbers, but it's easier to use like that in our case.

---

Now using this we can prime factorize the numbers $m$ and $n$. Also we use the fact $(m,n) = 1$, so all prime factors are different.

$$m = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3}...p_k^{a_k}$$
$$n = q_1^{b_1}q_2^{b_2}q_3^{b_3}...q_l^{b_l}$$

So we know that:

$$mn = r^2$$

Now doing the prime factorization on both sides and using the first property on the RHS, because obviously the prime factors are same, as they are same numbers we get:

$$p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3}...p_k^{a_k}q_1^{b_1}q_2^{b_2}q_3^{b_3}...q_l^{b_l} = p_1^{2c_1}p_2^{2c_2}p_3^{2c_3}...p_k^{2c_k}q_1^{2d_1}q_2^{2d_2}q_3^{2d_3}...q_l^{2d_l}$$

Divide the equation with the LHS we get:

$$1 = p_1^{2c_1-a_1}p_2^{2c_2-a_2}p_3^{2c_3-a_3}...p_k^{2c_k-a_k}q_1^{2d_1-b_1}q_2^{2d_2-b_2}q_3^{2d_3-b_3}...q_l^{2d_l-b_l}$$

Because the only factor of $1$ is $1$ it's obvious that every term on the RHS is $1$. So we have:

$$p_1^{2c_1-a_1} = 1 \iff 2c_1-a_1=0 \iff 2c_1=a_1$$

We do the same on all factors and we get that $a_1,a_2,a_3...a_k, b_1,b_2,b_3...b_l$ are multiple of two.

So using the second property we know that $m$ and $n$ are square numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with. I feel like I have (almost) all the important details, but I don't know if I explained it properly..

> Let the canonical form of $r$ be as follows:
>   \begin{equation*}
> r=p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}p_{2}^{\alpha_{2}}\cdots p_{r}^{\alpha_{r}}
> \end{equation*}
>   Therefore, the canonical form of $r^{2}$ is
>   \begin{equation*}
> r^{2}=p_{1}^{2\alpha_{1}}p_{2}^{2\alpha_{2}}\cdots p_{r}^{2\alpha_{r}}
> \end{equation*}
>   Given that $r^{2}=mn$, it follows that $mn=p_{1}^{2\alpha_{1}}p_{2}^{2\alpha_{2}}\cdots p_{r}^{2\alpha_{r}}$. If we break down $m$ and $n$, $m=p_{1}^{\beta_{1}}p_{2}^{\beta_{2}}\cdots p_{r}^{\beta_{r}}$ and $n=p_{1}^{\gamma_{1}}p_{2}^{\gamma_{2}}\cdots p_{r}^{\gamma_{r}}$. But since $(m,n)=1$, either $\beta_{i}=0$ or $\gamma_{i}=0$. In the case where $\beta_{i}=0$, $\gamma_{i}=2\alpha_{i}$, and where $\gamma_{i}=0$, $\beta_{i}=2\alpha_{i}$. Therefore,
>   \begin{align*}
> m&=(p_{1}^{\beta_{1}}p_{2}^{\beta_{2}}\cdots p_{r}^{\beta_{r}})^{2}\\
> n&=(p_{1}^{\gamma_{1}}p_{2}^{\gamma_{2}}\cdots p_{r}^{\gamma_{r}})^{2}
> \end{align*}
>   And $m$ and $n$ are squares.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: You should accept this answer (if you don't find any of the other answers acceptable).